# Installing vertical EMT conduit crossing a horizontal eletrical run

Tags: wiring, conduit, ethernet

The room i want to install some vertical EMT (for data cables) has a horizontal electrical wire (romex or something like it), about 8 or 10 inches from the floor, going across the entire wall as near as I can tell.

Now there is enough give, that I could push the romex to one side and install the conduit, but there is more tension than I would like. Is there any issue with pushing the electrical off center, and rubbing directly against metallic conduit?

Comment: Could you use 1/2" standoffs to lay the conduit over the NM-B cable? I'd personally want the shielded wiring to be outside the cable for protection.

Comment: I'm not understandong the geometry here. Are the wires against the wall surface, or centered in a wall space (passage holes drilled in the middle of  the 2x4s?   How are the wires protected from nails from the other side of the wall?

Comment: Wire is centered via holes in the middle of the studs. No protection provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having the NM-B in contact with the outside of some EMT. Just be sure it isn't located near a sharp edge.

Answer (score 1):

If you use conduit hangers like these:

If will hold the conduit ⅜" away from the wall giving the  NM cable plenty of room behind it.

Good luck with your project!

[image: conduit hanger]